# Version display on Right Click Open With on MAC OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have developed an app which supports opening of text file.
Everything is working fine but on right click on .txt files and check **'open with'** it displays my application with its version in brackets. '**TextEditor (1.0.0.0)**'

I want to display only Application name there. How can that be achieved. Like on .pdf it displays **'Adobe Reader'** not the version.

Comment: I suspect this only happens on your developer account.  Create a test account and install the app into `/Applications` like a real user would, and see what happens.

Comment: Yes we have tried that too on new machines. But it displays that like that only. :-(

Comment: My thinking is OSX can see more than one version of the app and so it is disambiguating with the version number.